# Functional Analysis (Normed Linear Spaces)

Tags: functional-analysis

Since every normed linear space is a vector space but every vector space is not necessarily a normed linear space. Give an example to show that a vector space is not a normed linear space that is norm can't be defined on the vector space. Please answer if someone knows.

Comment: You can always define a norm on any **real** vector space by choosing a basis $(b_i)_i$ and defining the norm of $\sum a_i b_i$ as (for example) $\sum |b_i|$. Note though that in general this will not yield a **complete** normed space.

Comment: To have a norm, the vector space must be a linear space over an infinite field with an absolute value function, such as $\mathbb{Q,R,C}$. In this case (for finite dimensional vector spaces), you can always define a norm by choosing a basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2},\ldots,\mathbf{e_n}\}$ and defining the norm of $\sum a_i\mathbf{e_i}$ to be $\sqrt{\sum |a_i|^2}$.
Other norms exist, such as the one given by @PhoemueX

Comment: @cmtappu96, you told that the vector space must be a linear space over an infinite field but I think we can define a norm on the trivial vector space over the trivial field {0,1}? Please guide me if I am wrong.

Comment: @WaqarAliShah Yes, you are right, you can define a norm on the trivial vector space. However till now I have only seen norms defined over rationals (rare, actually), reals or complex numbers. For example the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics) defines it over a _subfield of $\mathbb C$_. Besides, a norm over the trivial vector field would not be interesting to do geometry with, it would only serve as an example that satisfies all required axioms.